# Windows Server license

Tags: windows, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I keep getting this message on start-up about the license not being genuine.  I know it is genuine because I bought from an authorized dealer and there is this paper in a white envelope that proves that it is.  But how I do stop the message that keeps popping up and start receiving Windows updates over the internet?

Comment: @dave: This question does not belong on StackOverflow, since it is not about programming. Try SuperUser.com or ServerFault.com instead.  I'm not sure which of the two sites is the right place to ask your question, though... ;-)

Comment: Call up Microsoft and/or your authorised dealer and let them sort it out (possibly by issuing you a new license).

Comment: @ho11 This is not about the legal side - sometimes it happens a Windows server forgets it is licenses. It takes some tricks to sort that out, technically. Happens even when you run a KMS - not sure yet what gets stuck there.

Comment: I nominte for reopen. I use a KMS and I had the same happen to some servers here. Ended up reinstalling them. Somehow they get stuck in "not being licensed". This is a purely technical question and not related to the legal side (if the OP talks the truth).

Answer (score 3):

If it's genuine, you can safely call the Microsoft's support your are entitled to, so they can solve your problem.